# Loading image dynamically from drawer crashing the app

Tags: android

I am very new to android. I have to load images dynamically in to recycler view row. I am using the following code and application get crashing due to null object.

```
    String uri = "@drawable/menu_howtouse";
    int imageResource = this.context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, this.PACKAGE_NAME);

    Drawable res = this.context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    holder.iconImageView.setImageDrawable(res);
```

Comment: Post stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash could be because the context is `null`.

Try this code,

```
int imageResource = this.context.getResources().getIdentifier("menu_howtouse", "drawable", this.PACKAGE_NAME);
```

Make sure you have initialized `holder.iconImageView` as follows,

```
holder.iconImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView);
```

Comment: I tried as above and still I am getting the following error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
int imageResource = this.context.getResources().getIdentifier("menu_howtouse", "drawable", this.PACKAGE_NAME);

        Drawable res = this.context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
        holder.iconImageView.setImageDrawable(res);

Comment: Can you post the `getView` method?

Comment: Looks like you havn't initialized `iconImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter can be null, but you shouldn't need to set that.

You should be able to use this

```
context.getResources().getIdentifier("menu_howtouse", "drawable", this.PACKAGE_NAME);
```

If anything there is throwing a nullpointer, it is probably the `context` because those other methods don't throw any exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Is the same image to be added to every row you can do this:

```
holder.iconImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.menu_howtouse);

              OR
```

If multiple images form drawable to be added, then make list of all the Drawables

```
List<int> imageList = new ArrayList<int>();
imageList.add(R.drawable.iamge1);
imageList.add(R.drawable.iamge2);
imageList.add(R.drawable.iamge3);
```

pass this to adapter class

```
Adapter adp = new Adapter(context, imageList);
```

Then in **onBindViewHolder** do this

```
holder.iconImageView.setImageResource(imageList.get(position));

          -- OR --
```

you can try Picasso or glide, they are very simple to integrate